# Ajax function not working when passing one of the variables through parameter, PHP, JAVASCRIPT, AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to write a function to get the value from a select statement, and echo the value to the screen. It works when I put the exact select name inside of the ajax function, but it stopped working when I tried to pass the select name through the parameters. I know it was passed through the parameter successfully, and I know it was the right select name by alerting it to the screen inside the function when I was testing it. So I think the actual problem might be on this line:

```
data: { select: $('select[name=theName]').val()},
```

But I'm not sure what is wrong with it. I have 2 versions of my codes below. The first version works, and the second version doesn't. The first version has the exact select name inside the parameter, and the second version is passed through the parameter called 'theName'. Please take a look:

> ajax.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function ajax(url,theName,id) {
alert(theName)
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: { select: $('select[name="select1"]').val()},
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
           }

      });

}

</script>
```

> test1

```
<?php

echo "<select name = 'select1' onchange = 'ajax(\"test2.php\",\"select1\",\"output\")'>";

?>
```

^---This version works.

> ajax.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function ajax(url,theName,id) {
alert(theName)
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: { select: $('select[name=theName]').val()},
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
           }

      });

}

</script>
```

> test1

```
<?php

echo "<select name = 'select1' onchange = 'ajax(\"test2.php\",\"select1\",\"output\")'>";

?>
```

^---This version does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have omitted double quotes and concatenation here:

```
data: { select: $('select[name="'+theName+'"]').val()},
```

Comment: Good answer. What if I want to pass in the type too? Instead of having select inside, I want to pass the type through the parameter called type. I tried it this way, but it didn't work:  data: { select: $('type[name="'+theName+'"]').val()},

Comment: there is no such input as type. Name is just an attribute of select element. Read about css selectors.

Comment: No, I mean like the type. Like you know, select, input, radio buttons, check boxes. Those types.

Comment: oh, I see: data: { select: $(type+'[name="'+theName+'"]').val()},

Answer (score 1):

```
data: { select: $('select[name=' + theName + ']').val()},
```

Comment: Good answer. What if I want to pass in the type too? Instead of having select inside, I want to pass the type through the parameter called type. I tried it this way, but it didn't work: data: { select: $('type[name='+theName+']').val()},